# Only the left part of my buttons are clickable (JavaFX/FXML)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I started using JavaFX recently, and I have ran into an unusual problem in my code, that I'm feeling rather lost with.

Essentially, the buttons are correctly linked up in their controller, and clickable, but only on the left 1/4 part. It's almost acting as if something is infront of it.

I'll post the code below and cross my fingers that somebody sees something obvious that I don't. It took me two days of debugging why the buttons only sometimes worked, before I realised what the issue was when randomly clicking around.

Please bare in mind that this FXML is halfway through experimentation with different anchorpanes. The problem area can be found using CTRL+F "fooButton". It is the left hand side of a BorderPane.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane fx:id="mainWindow" prefHeight="461.0" prefWidth="760.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="guiControllers.MainController">
   <top>
      <Pane id="body" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="658.0" style="-fx-background-color: #243242; -fx-border-color: #0E141B; -fx-border-radius: 3;" stylesheets="@application.css" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="103.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="394.0" text="Title Here" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Calibri Bold" size="41.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <ImageView fitHeight="55.0" fitWidth="61.0" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="20.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../Res/mhlogo.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </top>
   <left>
      <AnchorPane BorderPane.alignment="TOP_CENTER">
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets />
         </BorderPane.margin>
         <children>
            <VBox id="buttonBar" fx:id="buttonBar" alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="170.0" minWidth="170.0" prefHeight="365.0" prefWidth="170.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2E4055; -fx-border-radius: 3; -fx-border-color: #0E141B;">
               <children>
                  <AnchorPane prefHeight="365.0" prefWidth="309.0">
                     <children>
                        <Pane layoutX="1.0" layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="167.0">
                           <children>
                              <Pane layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="-2.0" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="169.0" style="-fx-background-color: #565656; -fx-border-color: #000000; -fx-border-radius: 20; -fx-background-radius: 20;">
                                 <children>
                                    <ImageView fitHeight="19.0" fitWidth="18.0" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="7.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                       <image>
                                          <Image url="@../Res/magnifying-glass.png" />
                                       </image>
                                    </ImageView>
                                    <TextField layoutX="29.0" layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="134.0" style="-fx-border-radius: 1; -fx-border-color: #111111; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-background-color: #FFFFFF; -fx-background-radius: 20; -fx-border-radius: 20;" styleClass="stop-color-leaking" stylesheets="@../cSS/application.css" />
                                 </children>
                              </Pane>
                           </children>
                        </Pane>
                        <AnchorPane layoutX="3.0" layoutY="43.0">
                           <children>
                              <Button id="fooButton" fx:id="fooButton" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="TOP" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="167.0" minWidth="167.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadFooPame" prefWidth="167.0" style="-fx-background-color: #CDCDCD; -fx-border-color: #0E141B; -fx-border-radius: 3;" styleClass="mainFont" stylesheets="@../cSS/application.css" text="Find Patient" textAlignment="CENTER" textOverrun="CLIP" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />
                              <Button id="barButton" fx:id="barButton" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="TOP" layoutY="24.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="167.0" minWidth="167.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadBarPane" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="167.0" style="-fx-background-color: #CDCDCD; -fx-border-color: #0E141B; -fx-border-radius: 3;" styleClass="mainFont" stylesheets="@../cSS/application.css" text="Add Appointments" textAlignment="CENTER" textOverrun="CLIP" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                        <AnchorPane layoutX="1.0" layoutY="197.0" prefWidth="169.0">
                           <children>
                              <ImageView id="settingsButton" fitHeight="38.0" fitWidth="48.0" layoutX="64.0" layoutY="130.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@../Res/settings.png" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </left>
   <right>
      <TabPane id="tabPane" fx:id="tabPane" focusTraversable="false" prefHeight="365.0" prefWidth="166.0" rotateGraphic="true" style="-fx-background-color: # #414760;" styleClass="tab-header-background" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <tabs>
          <Tab fx:id="notesTab" text="Notes">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane maxWidth="400.0" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="200.0" prefHeight="336.0" prefWidth="216.0" style="-fx-border-color: #414760; -fx-background-radius: 3;" styleClass="tab-header-background" stylesheets="@../application/CSS/application.css" />
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab fx:id="diagramTab" closable="false" text="Diagram" />
        </tabs>
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="DEFAULT" />
         </cursor>
         <stylesheets>
            <URL value="@application.css" />
            <URL value="@../application/CSS/application.css" />
         </stylesheets>
      </TabPane>
   </right>
   <center>
      <AnchorPane id="centerAP" fx:id="centerAP" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
      </AnchorPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Any ideas?

Edit 2:

[image: Here is my scene].

Edit 2:

The problem ended up being the center panels being too large. Simple solution, strange problem to diagnose.

Comment: Are you using SceneBuilder? If so, when you select `Preview->Show Preview in Window`, can you click the buttons? If you could post a screenshot with the scene, that would probably help.

Comment: I'm unsure if pressing them works or doesn't, as they load a new FXML file new into the centre panel.I'll update now with a screenshot, thank you.

Comment: Can you remove the `-fx-background-color` style from the buttons and test again?

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. Totally puzzled with this one.

Comment: It works for me. I'm running your FXML, and I can click on the buttons. If you keep the background color you can't see their hover or selected state, but you can click on them either way, and you'll see that their onAction method is called. Remove your styling so you can see the default buttons styling.

Comment: Thank you for that tip. It hasn't solved the problem, but switching themes does let me see that the buttons are being clicked. Curious. I may try set the buttons up more programmatically and see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try removing your background-color and border-color from both buttons.
>   Then you can see a blue outline whenever you select a button.You can
>   use the **: focus** CSS pseudo-class to change the color or to give an effect when the button is selected.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I worked it out in the end by doing exactly this.